# Function calls from outside of $(document).ready to the function defined in the $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-calls

I wanna use $(window).resize to call some function when a mobile device orientation change, I wrote all my code inside the $(document).ready, this works when I use an Android device, but with iPhone after first orientation is detected it doesn't call $(window).resize even again. When I put the (window).resize function outside of $(document).ready, it also works on iPhone.

Inside this $(window).resize function, I have to make call to the methods which are defined in the $(document).ready block, so how can I do that?

Comment: simple thoughts... cant you make the function global??? or public or something like that? Take an look at this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960448/global-jquery-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960448/global-jquery-function)

Comment: simple thoughts... cant you make the function global??? or public or something like that?

Comment: Just take an look at this, and that should be enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960448/global-jquery-function

Comment: You have to assign them to a variable outside `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Could you post your code (a stripped-down version of it, please)?

Comment: @TWCrap my confusion was I'm doing parsing an XML with JQuery in $(document).ready, so before document isn't ready I cannot do parsing. I've overcome the iPhone resize problem by not dooing another JQuery parsing in it.

Comment: @FelixKling see my comment previous comment

Answer (score 2):

As you need to use something from two different event handlers, you should move that something out of the event handler. You can't create the methods in either event handler, because you can't know if `ready` or `resize` will be triggered first.

You can for example create an object that holds the methods:

```
var commonMethods = {
  data: 42,
  someMethod: function() { alert(this.data); }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  commonMethods.someMethod();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  commonMethods.someMethod();
});
```

Comment: But the question implies the resize handler is being defined inside the ready handler, so it doesn't look like a scope problem. Anyway, we can't be sure without seeing the code.

Comment: @bfavaretto: The resize handler is defined outside the ready handler, to work with iPhone. (Second sentence in the question.)

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, and your answer does answer the question in the title. My point is, I believe it should work with the resize handler defined inside the ready handler. I can't see why it wouldn't. iPhone oddity, maybe?

Comment: @bfavaretto: If you have the resize handler inside the ready handler, it can only handle resize event that happens after the ready event is triggered. (The resize handler would of course have to consider that the page might be only partially loaded to handle resize events before the ready event.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Guffa, I wasn't thinking about that scenario.

Comment: @Guffa my confusion was I'm doing parsing an XML with JQuery in $(document).ready, so before document isn't ready I cannot do parsing. I've overcome the iPhone resize problem by not dooing another JQuery parsing in it.

Answer (score 1):

Define your methods outside the `$(document).ready()` block.
Then only call them as you need them throughout the code. This way, you have access to them both from the `$(document).ready()` and the `$(window).resize()` blocks.

Comment: my confusion was I'm doing parsing an XML with JQuery in $(document).ready, so before document isn't ready I cannot do parsing. I've overcome the iPhone resize problem by not dooing another JQuery parsing in it.